# grep exact match in vector inside a list in R

Tags: r, regex, match

I have a list like this:

```
map_tmp <- list("ABC",
                c("EGF", "HIJ"),
                c("KML", "ABC-IOP"),
                "SIN",
                "KMLLL")


> grep("ABC", map_tmp)
[1] 1 3
> grep("^ABC$", map_tmp)
[1] 1  # by using regex, I get the index of "ABC" in the list
> grep("^KML$", map_tmp)
[1] 5  # I wanted 3, but I got 5. Claiming the end of a string by "$" didn't help in this case.
> grep("^HIJ$", map_tmp)
integer(0) # the regex do not return to me the index of a string inside the vector
```

How can I get the index of a string (exact match) in the **list**?
I'm ok not to use `grep`. Is there any way to get the index of a certain string (exact match) in the list? Thanks!

Comment: In this case, you will get unintended results because `map_tmp` is converted to `as.character(map_tmp)`.  You will need to use `lapply`

Answer (score 1):

Using lapply:

```
which(lapply(map_tmp, function(x) grep("^HIJ$", x))!=0)
```

The lapply function gives you a list of which for each element in the list (0 if there's no match). The `which!=0` function gives you the element in the list where your string occurs.

Comment: (1) `grep` would never return `0`. Comparing it with zero here only works because `list(integer(0)) != 0` is `NA`, and `which(NA)` is `integer(0)`.  (2) You have multiple items in two of the list elements, so if you get multiple matches in any element, this will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Use either mapply or Map with `str_detect` to find the position, I have run only for one string "**KML**" , you can run it for all others. I hope this is helpful.

First of all we make the lists even so that we can process it easily

```
library(stringr)
map_tmp_1 <- lapply(map_tmp, `length<-`, max(lengths(map_tmp)))
### Making the list even 
val <- t(mapply(str_detect,map_tmp_1,"^KML$"))

 > which(val[,1] == T)
[1] 3

 > which(val[,2] == T)
integer(0)
```

In case of "**ABC**" string:

```
val <- t(mapply(str_detect,map_tmp_1,"ABC"))
> which(val[,1] == T)
[1] 1
> which(val[,2] == T)
[1] 3
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I cannot explain why grep would work well in a list with characters but not with regex. Anyway, the best way I found to match a character string using common R script is:

```
map_tmp <- list("ABC",
                c("EGF", "HIJ"),
                c("KML", "ABC-IOP"),
                "SIN",
                "KMLLL")    
sapply( map_tmp , match  , 'ABC' )
```

It returns a list with similar structure as the input with 'NA' or '1', depending on the result of the match test:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] NA NA

[[3]]
[1] NA NA

[[4]]
[1] NA

[[5]]
[1] NA
```